# Online Map - Vector files postcode lookups - self serve, Mapbox or Gmaps?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, mapbox, vector-tiles

I've been reading around how to serve vector tiles to an online map and I have a few questions about which tools and services are best to use together for an application that has c.1.5 million map views a month.

We receive mapinfo files which are converted to geoJSON via OGR2OGR.  These are then converted to vector tiles using tippecanoe.  We have the option to serve these files via a self hosted node.js tile server.

I'm interested in using Leaflet for the web interface to the map and using OpenStreetMap vector tiles as the base map.  I understand that I can download and serve these myself but I think the preference would be to call them from OSM.

I love the stuff that Mapbox have been doing but in reality I'm not sure that I need Mapbox studio and we are able to serve the vectors ourselves.  What we do need however is a postcode lookup service and hopefully an address autocomplete service.  I am aware that Google and Mapinfo both offer these services (so long as I use their maps) but the cost is high for the number of monthly map views I require.  I know that Mapbox offers a load of other services for the price, but as I see it it is only access to the APIs that I need (if I serve my own vectors).

Are there alternative services I can use for postcode lookup / address autocomplete other than Google / Mapbox?

Comment: If UK based look at https://craftyclicks.co.uk/geocode/

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. You're essentially asking about geocoders, but you've begun with a long rambling question about vector tiles.

Comment: Do vector tiles segue into geocoding because you want some kind of reverse geocoding based on what feature is clicked on? Otherwise address autocomplete is a separate service, and I don't believe you need to use tiles hosted by Mapbox in order to use their separate address services.

Answer (score 1):

[Mapzen geocoding service](https://mapzen.com/projects/search/) may be a good fit for you. "...Mapzen Search completely powered by open data, but it is available to everyone..."